# Get values from STDClass Object and create new array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, stdclass

I need to pull the ShipQty from each of the following STDClass Objects and insert it into a new array.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [PRODUCTID] => 2 [ORDERID] => 7 [SHIPQTY] => 3 [STATUS] => 1 [SHIPDATE] => 2013-12-18 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [PRODUCTID] => 2 [ORDERID] => 5 [SHIPQTY] => 2 [STATUS] => 1 [SHIPDATE] => 2014-01-02 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [PRODUCTID] => 2 [ORDERID] => 2 [SHIPQTY] => 5 [STATUS] => 1 [SHIPDATE] => 2014-01-08 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [PRODUCTID] => 2 [ORDERID] => 1 [SHIPQTY] => 2 [STATUS] => 1 [SHIPDATE] => 2014-01-16 ) )
```

I want the following: `array(3,2,5,2)`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Luceos I've tried exactly what Emissary has posted below but not been able to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (assuming your array is named $myArr):

```php
$result = array();
foreach ($myArr as $obj) {
    $result[] = $obj->SHIPQTY;
}
```

Hope this helps.